# jQuery - Toggle element and save it with cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I am trying to use the jQuery Cookie plugin, and the jQuery toggle function:

Whenever someone toggle `#launchpad,` I want to get it's current state.

Example, if someone toggles it, and it becomes hidden, I then want to alert that it is now hidden - and vice versa.

This is my current code:

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
            if($.cookie){
                   //By default, if no cookie, just display.
                   $("#launchpad").toggle(!(!!$.cookie("toggle-state")) || $.cookie("toggle-state") === 'true');
            }

            $('#toggle-launchpad').on('click', function(){


                $("#launchpad").toggle(
                    if($(this).is(":visible")){
                        alert("visible!!");
                    }else{
                        alert("not visible");
                    }

                );
                //Save the value to the cookie for 1 day; and cookie domain is whole site, if ignore "path", it will save this cookie for current page only;
                $.cookie("toggle-state", $("#launchpad").is(':visible'), {expires: 1, path:'/'}); 
            });

        });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="launchpad">
            <div id="toggle-launchpad" title="Toggle Launchpad" style="display: ;">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I guess I cannot use an `if function`, inside the `toggle function`. Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do:

```
$("#launchpad").toggle(400, function() {
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
        alert("visible!!");
    }else{
        alert("not visible");
    }
});
```

the code will be executed when the `toggle` function has complete. Note that the `toggle` function is async, so your `$.cookie` call will likely be called *before* the div is hidden/shown. Try:

```
$("#launchpad").toggle(400, function() {
    $.cookie("toggle-state", $("#launchpad").is(':visible'), {expires: 1, path:'/'});
});
```

Not that 400 is the (default) time the animation will take in ms. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Edit: Incase your comment is about the first part of your code, I would write it as:

```
if ($.cookie && $.cookie("toggle-state")) && $.cookie("toggle-state") === 'false') {
     $("#launchpad").hide();
}
```

This assumes that the div is visible by default (i.e. not hidden by CSS)

Comment: How can I then check whether the #launchpad is visible or hidden, and display alerts accordingly?

Comment: I've created a little example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bddjtx5n/. However, you can still do `$(this).is(':visible')` or `$("#launchpad").is(':visible')` inside the anonymous function that is second parameter of the `toggle` function call.